# Parent ViewModel communicate child

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, mvvm

I have a main View with nested child Views. I have a main VM that holds instances of the child VMs.
At some point, the main VM needs to interact with child.

In the main VM. I defined the child ViewModel as

```
 public ChildViewModel VmChild
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.vmChild == null)
                this.vmChild = new ChildViewModel();
            return this.vmChild;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.vmChild != value)
            {
                this.vmChild = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("VmChild");
            }
        }
    }
```

In the main View. I have

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
     <localViews:ChildView DataContext="{Binding VmChild}"> </localViews:ChildView>
</StackPanel>
```

In the child view code behind.

```
public ChildViewModel ViewModel
{
    get
    {
        if (this.vmChild == null)
            this.vmChild = new ChildViewModel();
        return this.vmChild;
    }
    set
    {
        if (this.vmChild != value)
        {
            this.vmChild = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And

```
private void InitializeViewModel()
{
    if (this.DataContext is ChildViewModel)
    {
        this.ViewModel = this.DataContext as ChildViewModel;
    }
    else
    {
        this.DataContext = this.ViewModel;
    }
}
```

My question is my code works out. However it has an exception when I open the main view.

The exception is `NullReferenceException was thrown on "ChildView": Cannot create an instance of "ChildView"`. The error line is at  `this.vmChild = new ChildViewModel();`

I think that I defined the view model instance twice to cause it. In the main View Model I already define the child vm instance. In code behind of the child view, I defined it again. But I don't know how to fix it.

**EDIT:** 
[image]

Comment: _The error line is at `this.vmChild = new ChildViewModel();`_ but you have 2 of those lines. Which is very odd by itself.

Comment: That picture doesn't help if you don't tell us what's on line 82. But it looks like the problem may be inside that constructor.

Comment: The line 82 seems to be irreverent. It is a catch part code. Now the error becames "Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))". The thing is that I use your code. the `DataContext` is null. The reason is that the code reached the getter first. It has not been assigned a value in the ViewModel.

Comment: Then either your code or your bindings should be made more resilient to null values. Find the problem by removing parts until the error goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to 'fix' a null value scenario that shouldn't occur or should be left alone.

Remove both the pieces of the child's code-behind and if you really need a ViewModel property (is this for UWP?), use this:

```
// not normally needed in WPF/MVVM
public ChildViewModel ViewModel { get { return DataContext as ChildViewModel; } }
```

The Child View is *getting* a ViewModel, it shouldn't create one.

Comment: It is a silverlight project. Do I still need setter part? I use .NET 4 in Visual Studio 2010. It seems need setter.

Comment: No, you're setting the DataContext. The ViewModel doesn't need a setter.

Comment: But as I know C# 4.0 needs getter and setter together unless using C# 6. And the error is still there.

Comment: C#1 could do without a setter.

Answer (score 0):

In main view replace

```
DataContext="{Binding VmEChild}
```

with

```
DataContext="{Binding VmChild}
```

Comment: Sorry, it is the typo in the question. I reedit it. It is not the real cause.

Comment: Question code shouldn't have typos. Always copy/paste from the actual code.